# Common factors /greatest common factors /least common factor

Tags: factorial

See I am baffling with the concept of above mentioned title 
I saw one question they wrote find common factors /gcf/lcm of 42,294,882 
Please help me out in getting the concept
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried opening the respective wikipedia pages?
It's just a matter of decomposing a natural number in the unique product of its *prime divisors*. Then comparing the decompositions of two numbers gives you the looked for information.

Comment: I am not getting please,share me a link

Comment: Basically ,I want to know the difference between prime factors and common factors

Comment: the *common factors* are the *prime factors* two number have in common. (Clearly this is not **the** definition of common factors, but it's the one which came to my mind)

Comment: Means common factors and prime are same only once we find prime  factors than two same numbers in common are common factors ?

Comment: yes. That's why they are called **common**

Comment: Can you please ,provide me some links for studying maths from beginning

Comment: Is there any shortcut to find common factors

Comment: I unfortunately don't know any (good) textbook for your level, although I may think that any basic text will do. Maybe someone else can help you.
There are, just google a bit and you will find how to to check if a number is divisible by $2,3,5,7$ and $11$ (there are probably more, but I don't know about those)
I won't comment further since this is not a chat. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common Factors: All the factors which divides the given numbers.
In your case: Common factors are: 2, 3, 7, 21, 42 as these numbers divide all three numbers.

G.C.F. - Greatest Common factor - The greatest number which divides all these numbers. In your case, it is 42.

L.C.M. - Lowest Common Multiple - The number which is divisible by all these numbers

Now as you know:
$$ 42 = 2 \times 3 \times 7 $$
$$ 294 = 2 \times 3 \times 7 \times 7 $$
$$ 882 = 2 \times 3 \times 3 \times 7 \times 7 $$

$$ L.C.M. = 2 \times 3 \times 3 \times 7 \times 7  =  882$$

Comment: What will be the h.c.f  for 108,24?

Comment: Find the factors and look at the common factors and multiply them.

Comment: Yes I ticked because up vote requires 15reputation I am new  to this platform

Comment: Thanks, I hope I was helpful to you

Comment: Sir ,in the above question I am getting hcf 42 .

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Now, I have edited

Comment: Sir,please suggest me some cool  shortcut trick for  finding L.C.M

Comment: Google - Prime factorization method.